# MBP 13" 2016 fast power discharge, no apps using significant battery

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, power-management

I have a relatively new MBP 13" 2016 which used to use discharge at 5 - 10 watts without any intensive apps. Today, while unplugged, I noticed my battery discharging at 15 - 20 watts despite closing every app, turning off wifi, and disabling time machine, reducing brightness to medium.

Is there any better way to see what's using energy so consistently? I've tried Activity Monitor and looking at energy impact, but closing every relevant app which spikes energy usage seems to have no affect

Any ideas what could cause it, or how I could fix?

Below are some results from my activity monitor

[image]

Comment: Perhaps coconutBattery is not reporting the data correctly if you're running a beta version of macOS.

Comment: The shell program iTerm2 is whats using your battery. I'll rewrite my answer to reflect this new info.

Comment: The CPU time indicates that iTerm2 has been running for over a day (25 hours+)...... You state in the answer "Today, while unplugged, I noticed my battery discharging at 15 - 20 watts despite closing every app, turning off wifi, and disabling time machine, reducing brightness to medium."  Its clear that iTerm2 is the source of the drain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the results of your activity monitor screenshots, it is clear that the bash (shell) program ITerm2 is what is killing your battery. We can see this from the average energy impact of 66.25 and the CPU usage of 67%. This means the program is using over 25% of your Mac's CPU (2x CPUs = 200% total).

If you did not start this program, you should (force) quit it. The fact that it has been running over 1 day (25:42:52 CPU Time), and the fact that the problem just showed up today indicates that it is the source of the drain. Perhaps something has gone wrong and it is stuck in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but Activity Monitor Energy/CPU was one of the first things I checked. System usage stays at about 30%, biggest thing eating up CPU seems to be BASH. I'll see if the GPU tracker elucidates anything though!

Comment: @Pyloid Good, please edit the post to please say so and post the results...

Comment: I did say I checked activity monitor, but I'll post the results!

Comment: I can't thank you enough, that was completely correct. Bsh got stuck in a loop and kept my CPU on. I killed it and it solved the problem. Power usage back down to 8 watts. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for posting the screenshots. They helped alot. Good luck with your programming.